# Constraining types in GADT constructor

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-constraints, gadt, type-families

I've a simple ADT

```
data Concept a = Entity  a |  Role a | Relation a | Resource a | Sub (Concept a)
```

Now I want to create a GADT using this ADT that will constrain the type signature of it's constructors. This code won't work but I want to do something like this:

```
data Construct a b where
      Has :: Concept a -> 'Resource b -> Construct (Concept a) ('Resource b)
```

I.e. `Has` constructor for `Construct` can have first type param as a `Concept` of any form but the second type param should be a `Resource` constructor (promoted to be a type). This signature is failing as am using kind in place of type. But I want to realise something like this and am failing to wrap my head around how to do the same.

I'm importing `{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeInType #-}`.

Edit:

Based on one comment, if I do this

```
 data Construct (a :: Concept ak) (b :: Concept bk)  where
  Has :: Construct a ('Resource b)
```

Then it's is type-checking. But now how can I extract values when pattern matching on `Has`

```
f :: Construct a b -> T.Text
f Has = ???
```

My requirement is I want to constrain types for `Has a b` constructor so that it can only allow `a :: Concept ak` (i.e. any Concept) and `(b ~ 'Resource *) => (b :: Concept bk)`[1] (i.e. only Resource type of Concept) e.g.

```
-- Concept values
person = Entity "person"
name = Resource "name"
role = Role "father"

-- I want this to be valid
personHasName = Has person name

-- And this to be invalid
personHasRole = Has person role
```

[1] - After some reading of Constraints in Kinds, Type Families & Singleton Types, I guess it's possible to realise this kind of constraint via these principles. But I am completely at loss to make it work

Comment: Forget the kind/type problem, why is the second argument of your _constructor_ a _type_?

Comment: The code here is so thoroughly off, and also so thoroughly reduced, that it's pretty much impossible to tell what you're trying to accomplish. Could you please give some more context explaining what you're trying to do, what you want the types to mean, how you intend to use them, etc.?

Comment: If you want your code to typecheck, just remove the first `'Resource`: `Has :: Concept a -> Construct (Concept a) ('Resource b)`. But I would guess that you want *both* your fields to be promoted to types; in which case, you want something like `Has :: Construct (x :: Concept a) ('Resource b)`; in this case, you probably also want to declare the *kind* of your type: `data Construct (a :: Concept ak) (b :: Concept bk) where Has :: Construct a ('Resource b)`

Comment: @user2407038: I've updated the post based on your suggestions but have some more questions that I've also added to the post.

Comment: @dfeuer apologise for the vagueness earlier, I've edited the post with more information & have tried to clarify my intent. Hope it helps now

Comment: I'm fairly certain you need a type family `Has :: Concept -> Constraint`. Since the `Has` relation has no semantic, you need to create meaning yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Cale at #haskel-beginners for suggesting this solution by introducing a phantom type and tagging the same in the `Concept` GADT

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data ConceptType = EntityT | RoleT | RelationT | ResourceT | SubT ConceptType

data Concept (t :: ConceptType) a where
  Entity :: a -> Concept EntityT a
  Role :: a -> Concept RoleT a
  Relation :: a -> Concept RelationT a
  Resource :: a -> Concept ResourceT a
  Sub :: Concept t a -> Concept (SubT t) a

data Construct t a b where
  Has :: Concept t a -> Concept ResourceT b -> Construct t a b
```